# fsockopen() is enabled but doesn't work

Tags: php, fsockopen

I checked fsockopen using this code and the function is enabled.

```
<?php
if(function_exists('fsockopen')) {
     echo "fsockopen function is enabled";
}
else {
     echo "fsockopen is not enabled";
}
?>
```

Below is the code used by the script I need to work with. It is returning error: The fsockopen-function isn't working, error: 110 Connection timed out - FAILED

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == "on") $url = "https://";
else $url = "http://";
$url .= $HTTP_HOST.$REQUEST_URI;
$querystring = "action=fsockopentest";
if (@strpos($url, "/", 8)) {
    $urlpath = "/".substr($url, strpos($url, "/", 8)+1);
    $urldomain = substr($url, 0, strpos($url, "/", 8));
} else {
    $urlpath = "/";
    $urldomain = $url;
}
$urldomain = str_replace("http://", "", $urldomain);
$postheader = "POST $urlpath HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: $urldomain\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\nContent-Length: ".strlen ($querystring)."\r\n\r\n";
$fp = @fsockopen ($urldomain, 80, $errno, $errstr, 10);
$res = "";
if ($fp) {
    fputs ($fp, $postheader.$querystring);
    while (!feof($fp)) $res .= fgets ($fp, 1024);
    fclose ($fp);
}
if (strstr($res,"SUCCESS")) echo "<li>The fsockopen-function is working - <font color=\"#009900\">PASSED</font></li>";
else echo "<li>The fsockopen-function isn't working, error: $errno $errstr - <font color=\"#FF0000\">FAILED</font></li>";

echo "</ul>";
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: A lot of things might be wrong. Where are you connecting to?

Comment: There's a whole lot of hand-written code in there that could have gone wrong when determining the hostname fed to `fsockopen()`. Might I suggest using [`parse_url()`](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) instead?

Answer (score 0):

```
error: 110 Connection timed out - FAILED
```

Is a result of the inability of the fsocks function to connect to the server given in the allotted time.

This may be a problem with the URL or you not giving the timeout a lengthy enough time.